# Python type appears to be determined by later code instead of current type

Tags: python, types

I am puzzled by this Python code that I just implemented (simplified for SO).

```
userInput = 'invalid'
while userInput.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
    print('Do you want to continue? (y/n)')
    userInput = input
```

This code has a bug on the fourth line - it should be userInput = input()

However, when the code is run, it *immediately* errors on line number two with the message **AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'lower'**

My understanding is that the type of userInput at this point should have been a string.

Fixing the error on line four causes the program to behave as expected - that is, it no longer errors out on line 2.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here, or is this something subtle in how Python determines type? Python version is 3.6.12.

Comment: It doesn't error out _immediately_.  The error is on the second loop invocation.  Due to the bug, the loop runs continuously without waiting for user input, and of course the second invocation happens very quickly.

Comment: Oh... of course. I am facepalming. Thanks for spotting that, it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so fast you can't see.

The code is executing and when it goes to the second iteration with type changed it raises the error. You are probably missing that the message you wrote is printed before error.

Comment: Thanks. This should teach me to not write questions on SO before I've had my morning coffee.

Answer (score 0):

In Python types are linked to the object itself and not the name. So when you type `userInput=input` the name is reassigned to a function object and the stringvalue 'invalid' is no longer relevant. Then in line 2 you try to access `userInput.lower`, however `userInput` is now bound to the function `input`, and `input` has no attribute called `lower` which causes the AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

After you excecute your code u should see the print out first "Do you want to continue? (y/n)" and then throw the error.

Your 3rd line of code reassign the `userInput:str` type to built-in function `Input`

I would suggest the following

```
userInput = 'invalid'
while userInput.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
     userInput = input('Do you want to continue? (y/n)')
     print("My input is {}".format(userInput))
else:
    print("finish input")
```

Hope it helps you thanks!